# Communication between WebPage and Chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, web, google-chrome-extension

These Code snippets work correclty if my web application and my chrome extension are both in localhost. But, when i moved my web application to Amazon aws, the intended behaviour changed.

Script in index of my web application:

```
    function sendMessage(reqType, value, id) {
       var data = { from: "FROM_PAGE",reqType: reqType , value: value, id: id};
       window.postMessage(data, "*");
    };

    ...

    //Function call
    sendMessage("CANI",val,id);
```

Content Script of my chrome Extension:

```
    window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
       if (e.data.from && (e.data.from == "FROM_PAGE")) {
       //Request types received
           if(e.data.reqType == "CANI"){
             console.log("RECEIVED");
           }
       }
    });
```

My manifest includes my domain in `externally_connectable` parameter and my content script is also in `content_scripts` field. I tried many different solutions but none resulted. I thought that window object could be diferent in both scripts, but according to [chrome extensions documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), content script and the application web page, share the same DOM.

If you could give me a hint or a solution for the problem it would be very nice

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Comment: I already tried but gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener'` in content script.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Uh, you can use CustomEvent, there are many examples.